# How to hide the number on the constellation points in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

[image]

This is how you plot a constellation:

```
hMod = comm.RectangularQAMModulator('ModulationOrder',32, ...
'SymbolMapping','binary');

constellation(hMod)
```

but how do you hide the numbers above each constellation point?

I looked on Mathworks website but I did not find what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will do this job:

```
hMod = comm.RectangularQAMModulator('ModulationOrder',32, ...
'SymbolMapping','binary');

constellation(hMod)
delete(findobj(gca,'Type','Text'));
```

Its output is:

[image]